# multithreading dataframe merging python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I am just new to multithreading. Luckily, my code is partially working. The problem I encountered is some of the dataframes from other files are not merged into the combined dataframe.

Is there a possible solution to this? Thank you very much.

```
import os, pandas as pd
import threading

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

df = pd.DataFrame()
def merging(f):
    #shortened
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

threads = []
for f in files:
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=merging, args=(f,))
    thread1.start()
    threads.append(thread1)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]? Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to merge and transform files then save it after. In the codes above, I just focus on the part that after opening the files, the next step is to append the dataframes in a for loop. However, because of multithreading, some of dataframes are not included in the combined dataframe.

Comment: Is multithreading the appropriate choice over multiprocessing here? You haven't shared the code which does the merging, by the way. It's difficult to do much with such an abstract example.

Comment: @AMC, df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution for this? I could give it a try if we had more information on the problem/program.

Comment: @AMC, thank you very much... i think code is reproducible provided that the directory has files of similar contents... I was actually able to finish it before but I am not sure if the code has improved the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to read about queue to return the values of the threads:

```
import os, pandas as pd
import threading, queue

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

df = pd.DataFrame()
def merging(f):
    #shortened
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    return data

FILE_QUEUE = queue.Queue()
THREADS = []

for f in files:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda q, arg1: q.put(merging(arg1)), args=(FILE_QUEUE, f))
    thread.start()
    THREADS.append(thread)

for thread in THREADS:
    thread.join()

while not FILE_QUEUE.empty():
    data = FILE_QUEUE.get()
    df = df.append(data, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```